# Powershell: changing specific text in a file based on filename, then renaming said file to the same as the changed text

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of txt files with references to PDF files wich share the same name as the txt file.

The problem is these files have too long file names.
These txt and pdf files are autogenerated, and i have no way to change the filename length before i recieve them.

So what i have to do is open all the files, find the file name in the file based on it's file name, change the file name to something with max 16 characters+extension (total 20 characters)
and then output the textfile with the new filename and also rename the corresponding PDF to the new filename.

Im very new to Powershell, and after googling for about two days i have found something like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Test\Done" -recurse -include *.txt 
foreach ($file in $files){
$outputfile = (Get-Date).hour + (Get-Date).minute + (Get-Date).millisecond + ".txt"
Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {$_ -replace '$file', '$outputfile' ` }
Set-Content $outputfile }
```

But i feel i am far from what i am really after.

Does anyone know how i might go about making this script do what i want?

Kristoffer

EDIT:

I tried @Christian 's solution and it seemed to work, but it didn't edit and add a new file name inside the file.

I tried this just as a test:

```
$files = "testfil2.txt" 
$output = "testfil3.txt"
(Get-Content "C:\test\done\1456390000.txt") | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $files, $output  } | Set-Content "C:\test\done\1456390000.txt"
```

I removed the '' from the variables in ForEach-Object and it works as intended, it finds the variable $files and changes it with $output.
However when i do the same with @Christian 's script i get an error message:

```
Regular expression pattern is not valid: C:\Test\Done\1542644000.txt.
At line:7 char:39
+ (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-object {$_ -replace $file, $outputfile  } | Set-Co ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Test\Done\1542644000.txt:PSObject) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Any ideas?

Answered by Christian below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be work:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Test\Done" -recurse -include *.txt
$i = 0
foreach ($file in $files){

$outputfile = "{0}{1}{2}{3}.txt" -f (Get-Date).hour , (Get-Date).minute , (Get-Date).millisecond , ([string]$i).padleft(3,'0')

(Get-Content $file) | 
Foreach-object {
$_.replace(("$($file.name)" -replace '.txt',''), ("$outputfile" -replace '.txt',''))}| 
Set-Content $file 

rename-item $file $outputfile
rename-item ($file -replace '.txt','.pdf') ($outputfile -replace '.txt','.pdf') 

$i++
}
```

Comment: i updated my original post with a few questions if you wouldn't mind having a look? Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @user1875531 Have you tried my edited asnwer : {$_.replace("$($file.name)", "$outputfile") } ??

Comment: That works great!, except that the information in the txt files have the .pdf extension, so looking for testfile.txt wont change textfile.pdf, do you know how i can achieve the same result but without file extensions?

Comment: I figured i could use $file.BaseName to remove the extension problem when trying to find the information in the file, but seeing as you have set $outputfile to include ".txt" the name in the file becomes testfile.txt.pdf wich doesn't help much. so i tried removing it but then it just renames the txt file without and extension.. any ideas? :)

Comment: @user Try now, I've edited the involved line for the text replacement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christian this works exactly like i want it to! you just saved my ass =) thanks alot!